# How do I change instance when debugging Eclipse through Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I have a Java servlet application to maintain and have downloaded both the Live version and the Test version rom SVN to Eclipse (Helios) and have associated my Tomcat 7 with Eclipse to debug the applications.  But when I attempt to Run or Debug the Test instance of the servlet on the associated Tomcat server Tomcat always seems to start the Live instance.  For example when I attempt to start the Live Instance - in Eclipse it shows the URL to be;

```
https://localhost:8443/SWFinanceLive/WEB-INF/classes/path/to/web/request/entry/point.java
```

When I am expecting;

```
https://localhost:8443/SWFinanceTest/WEB-INF/classes/path/to/web/request/entry/point.java
```

How do I change the instance when running through the server in Eclipse?

This link seemed promising but then doesn't tell you how to change the setting;

[tomcat server instance debugging in the eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23161197/tomcat-server-instance-debugging-in-the-eclipse)

Comment: I vaguely recall that it's perhaps too easy to set a given server as the default for an application.  To change the server, you have to go into Run Configurations and make the change there.  Be sure to uncheck the flag that makes the choice the default so that it prompts you each time you run/debug.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want but right click on your project > Web Project Settings and change the context root to what you want.

Comment: @susie This might help thanks.  I will try it out but might be tomorrow before I get a chance to respond

Comment: @Susie Thanks this helped a lot.  I now have things working as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the assistance of @Susie I was able to change the project root context.  Things are working as I desire now